# How to automise frequently made calls to an API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nestjs

Im facing an issue and was wondering if there is some library/framework or something to help me out.

Basically i have method in an API that creates an object for me but the problem is that this is not returned to me right away but is created later in time.

all i get is a guid on method call and have to manually check in the future if my object is created and if it isnt try again.

So my wish is to somehow automise this maybe? My thoughts were for using jobs or mqueues.

Any suggestions are really appreciated. The languages im allowed to use is nestjs or spring boot.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the object. Please tell us more

Comment: I have a bunch of systems that will call my API. .My API  will be useed for user management. i will call a method to lets say create a user. there will be more CRUD methods. it will return  a guid. with this guid i will call another method to get the status of this user ccreation. Success, Failed, Pending. depending on the answer  i would continue with the creation. abort the creation or try again. and this sometimes may take a while depending on the creation API im calling and how busy it is. Is this enough details?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to set up a [dynamic cron job](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-cron-jobs) after your API kicks off the event, and then have those cron jobs possibly create more cron jobs or send out notifications. Not sure what the Spring Boot alternative would be, but a CRON is definitely what it sounds like you need (at least to me)

Comment: Thanks. Yes you understood the problem. But I wanted to see if this could be handled without jobs. Or with jobs but with some neet trick

Comment: I don't get it. You want to do something  at a later date/time but not use jobs? And you want it automated and re-runnable, but still don't want jobs?

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Im just looking for alternatives if there are any so that we write this code in the best way possible.